# AjaxPro request times out early in Safari

Tags: .net, ajax, safari, cross-browser, ajaxpro

I have the following issue that is only occurring safari (5.1 on Windows and 6 on a Mac), I am using AjaxPro to send a request by doing :

```
AjaxPro.timeoutPeriod = 1800000;
var r = new AjaxPro.Request();
r.url = this.url;
return r.invoke(method, args);
```

The problem is that in Safari, it seems regardless of what I set `AjaxPro.timeoutPeriod` it always times out in about 10 seconds, increasing the number seems to have no effect. According to my research, there seems to be a bug in the `setTimeout` method in Safari,  Does anyone know how to increase the timeout period in Safari or a workaround that would resolve the issue?

Comment: AjaxPro does not support Safari.

Comment: AjaxPro is old, old, old. The chances it supports modern browsers gets less and less as time goes on.